# Trouble Shooting Projectiles Upward in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, pygame, python-requests

I'm in the process of writing a duel-player tank game, similar to one known as "Tank Trouble". Of course, I'm only in the baby steps of it right now and I'm a bit stuck on a particular little bug. At the moment, the code below enables me to display my sprite, able to move around in all the directions, and also able to shoot projectiles. The only issue, however, is that it can only shoot projectiles left or right. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to change this so that the tank can shoot upward, when facing upward and downward, when facing downward? It can only shoot left and right, even when it is facing up or down, which is kind of odd. I am having trouble accessing the y-axis and having the projectile travel along it.

If anyone can find out how to do that and tell me what the new code is and where to place it, that would help a ton. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
tankImg = pygame.image.load("tank1.png")
downTank = tankImg 
leftTank = pygame.image.load("left1.png")
rightTank = pygame.image.load("right1.png")
upTank = pygame.image.load("up1.png")
bg = pygame.image.load("background.png")


screenWidth = 500
screenHeight = 500

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.up = False
        self.down = False

    def draw(self,screen):
        screen.blit(tankImg,(self.x,self.y))        

class projectile(object):
    def __init__(self,x, y, radius, color, facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing 

    def draw(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)

def redraw():
    screen.blit(bg, (0,0))
    tank.draw(screen)

    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()

run = True
tank = player(300, 410, 16, 16)
bullets = []
while run:

    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.x < screenWidth and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        elif bullet.y > screenHeight and bullet.y > 0:
            bullet.y += bullet.vel 
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))



    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and tank.x > tank.vel:
        tank.left = True
        tankImg = leftTank
        tank.x -= tank.vel
        facing = -1
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and tank.x < 500 - tank.width:
        tank.right = True
        tankImg = rightTank
        tank.x += tank.vel
        facing = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and tank.y > tank.vel:
        tank.up = True
        tankImg = upTank
        tank.y -= tank.vel
        facing = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and tank.y < 500 - tank.height:
        down = True
        tankImg = downTank
        tank.y += tank.vel
        facing = -1
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if len(bullets) < 1:
            bullets.append(projectile(round(tank.x + tank.width // 2), round(tank.y + tank.height // 2), 4, (0,0,0),facing))

    redraw()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused in that part of the code:

> ```py
> if bullet.x < screenWidth and bullet.x > 0:
>    bullet.x += bullet.vel
> elif bullet.y > screenHeight and bullet.y > 0:
>    bullet.y += bullet.vel 
> else:
>    bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
> ```

As long the bullet is in bounds of the window, the 1st condition evaluates `True`. That causes that the bullet can move in x-direction only.

Instead of the `facing` attribute add a `direction` attribute to the class `projectile`. Furthermore add a method (`move`) which moves the projectile. This method ignores the bounds of the window:

```py
class projectile(object):
    def __init__(self,x, y, radius, color, direction):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.direction = direction
        self.vel = 8

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.direction[0] * self.vel
        self.y += self.direction[1] * self.vel

    def draw(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)
```

Move the bullets in a loop end evaluate if a bullet is in bounds of the window. This can be done with ease, by using [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint):

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    for bullet in bullets[:]:
        bullet.move()
        window_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
        if not window_rect.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)):
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
```

Set the direction of the bullet dependent on the moving direction of the tank:

```py
direction = (-1, 0)
while run:
    # [...]

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and tank.x > tank.vel:
        tank.left = True
        tankImg = leftTank
        tank.x -= tank.vel
        direction = (-1, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and tank.x < 500 - tank.width:
        tank.right = True
        tankImg = rightTank
        tank.x += tank.vel
        direction = (1, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and tank.y > tank.vel:
        tank.up = True
        tankImg = upTank
        tank.y -= tank.vel
        direction = (0, -1)
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and tank.y < 500 - tank.height:
        down = True
        tankImg = downTank
        tank.y += tank.vel
        direction = (0, 1)
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if len(bullets) < 1:
            px, py = round(tank.x + tank.width // 2), round(tank.y + tank.height // 2)
            bullets.append(projectile(px, py, 4, (0,0,0), direction))
```

---

[image]

---

I recommend to spawn the bullets in the `pygame.KEYDOWN` event instead of the evaluating the pressed keys (`keys[pygame.K_SPACE]`). The event occurs once when a button is pressed. So every time when <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is pressed a single bullet is generated (Of course that is up to you):

```py
direction = (-1, 0)
while run:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:            
            if event. key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                px, py = round(tank.x + tank.width // 2), round(tank.y + tank.height // 2)
                bullets.append(projectile(px, py, 4, (0,0,0), direction))

    for bullet in bullets[:]:
        bullet.move()
        window_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
        if not window_rect.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)):
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and tank.x > tank.vel:
        tank.left = True
        tankImg = leftTank
        tank.x -= tank.vel
        direction = (-1, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and tank.x < 500 - tank.width:
        tank.right = True
        tankImg = rightTank
        tank.x += tank.vel
        direction = (1, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and tank.y > tank.vel:
        tank.up = True
        tankImg = upTank
        tank.y -= tank.vel
        direction = (0, -1)
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and tank.y < 500 - tank.height:
        down = True
        tankImg = downTank
        tank.y += tank.vel
        direction = (0, 1)

    redraw()
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, if bullet.x is between 0 and the screen width the first condition is met and the second is not checked

```
for bullet in bullets:
    if bullet.x < screenWidth and bullet.x > 0:
        # When this is True then the "elif" is not run
        bullet.x += bullet.vel
    elif bullet.y > screenHeight and bullet.y > 0:
        bullet.y += bullet.vel 
    else:
        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
```

You should just have one condition that makes sure the bullet is in both the x and y bound so that you update both x and y

```
for bullet in bullets:
    if 0 < bullet.x < screenWidth and 0 < bullet.y < screenHeight:
        bullet.x += bullet.vel
        bullet.y += bullet.vel 
    else:
        bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
```

You can combine conditions like this that check if a value is between 2 values like so `min < value < max`